# How can I modify my SQL subquery to get my query to work?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So basically, I know SQL doesn't allow this, but I wish I could do this because it's the only way I can think of to make my query.

So for example, say that there are 2 delivery trucks heading to the address '55 Alaska Rd.' with some items to deliver.

- 1 truck has 100 iPads and 200 iPhones
- 1 truck has 150 iPads

I am happily monitoring them by running this query:

```
[select truck.truck_id,
        truck.driver_name,
        truck.current_location,
        item.prtnum,
        item.quantity
   from truck,
        box,
        item,
        shipment
  where item.box_id = box.box_id 
    and box.truck_id = truck.truck_id
    and truck.ship_adr = shipment.ship_adr 
    and shipment.ship_adr = '55 Alaska Rd.']
```

It tells me who my 2 guys are, their current location, and what they're carrying. It returns 3 rows:

```
 | Truck ID | Driver Name | Current Location | Item Number | Item Quantity |
 |---TRK83--|---Gene R.---|------Hwy 18------|----iPad-----|------100------|
 |---TRK83--|---Gene R.---|------Hwy 18------|---iPhone----|------200------|
 |---TRK59--|---Jill M.---|------Hwy 894-----|----iPad-----|------150------|
```

Then my manager calls me and DEMANDS that I send him this same query, but modified so that it only returns trucks that have 1 item on it. So in this instance, he only wants the last row to be returned, because it only has iPads on it, and the other one has iPads and iPhones.

This is how I wish I could do it.

```
[select t.truck_id,
        t.driver_name,
        t.current_location,
        i.prtnum,
        i.quantity
   from item i,
        box b,
        truck t,
        shipment s
  where i.box_id = b.box_id 
    and b.truck_id = t.truck_id
    and t.truck_id in (select tr.truck_id,
                              decode(max(it.prtnum), min(it.prtnum), max(it.prtnum), 'Mixed Items') prtnum
                         from item it,
                              box bo,
                              truck tr
                        where it.box_id = bo.box_id
                          and bo.truck_id = tr.truck_id
                          and tr.truck_id = t.truck_id
                          and prtnum != 'Mixed Items'
                     group by tr.truck_id) p
    and t.ship_adr = s.ship_adr 
    and s.ship_adr = '55 Alaska Rd.']
```

That subquery is supposed to be selecting only the trucks in the parent query that do not have Mixed Parts on it. But that doesn't work because:

1. I can only have "tr.truck_id" in the subquery select; the decode can't also be there, but I don't know where else to put it.
2. I can't use the alias "prtnum" like that.

Does anyone know how I can achieve what my hypothetical boss wants me to do? Does anyone have any ideas on how I can alter the query to make it only select the trucks that have 1 item in it? I am going to have to change a lot of queries to do this, and I just can't figure out a good clean way. Or even a bad way that works.

Thank you for reading, and thank you for any help!

Comment: Rather than just adding several database vendor tags, why not stick to the one you're having the issue on?

Comment: I'm not sure what database vendor tags are. Can you rephrase? If you're asking why I need to add a subquery, it's because there are a LOT of queries like this that I need to modify, and I can't change them all. If I could just add in a subquery, that wouldn't interfere with the whole query, it would just limit it which is all I need to do.

Comment: You added `mysql`, `oracle`, and `sql-server` tags. Which of these are you working on? Just adding extra tags in order to draw attention won't make it easy to give you a solution that might work on the specific platform you're using.

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle of 3 different products. And one of them can have a bit odd GROUP BY behavior... That's why you should specify which product you are using!

Comment: Use of the `decode` function suggests Oracle, I've edited the tags

Comment: This is actually for SQL Server and Oracle. I just need database help. With the concepts of nesting subqueries I think. Unless there is a better solution. But I'm thinking the only way might be to put a subquery inside of the subquery. I just came here for database guidance and hopefully to share ideas about query design. If I were to limit it to one language that would have made me miss out I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Not having your dataset makes it a bit awkward but, as you only want the single count rows a GROUP BY with a trailing HAVING clause may fix the problem:

```
SELECT truck.truck_id,
        truck.driver_name,
        truck.current_location,
        item.prtnum,
        item.quantity
   FROM truck,
        box,
        item,
        shipment
  WHERE item.box_id = box.box_id 
    AND box.truck_id = truck.truck_id
    AND truck.ship_adr = shipment.ship_adr 
    AND shipment.ship_adr = '55 Alaska Rd.'
  GROUP BY truck.truck_id,
        truck.driver_name,
        truck.current_location
  HAVING COUNT(item.quantity) = 1
```

Comment: I think the OP wants count( item,prtnum  ) to be 1

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Thanks for your help, but I'm needing only the trucks that have 1 KIND of item on it. So I have 2 trucks. One has iPads and iPhones on it (two different item.prtnum's). The other has only iPads on it. I need the query to only return the truck that has only the 1 item on it (the one that has only the iPads on it). The "decode" i think is the key to helping me here. It can tell if a truck has "Mixed Items" or not. "decode(max(it.prtnum), min(it.prtnum), max(it.prtnum), 'Mixed Items') prtnum". I just don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: No need for an aggregate function for item.quantity in the select list? (Since it's not listed in the GROUP BY.)

Comment: In addition to what @jarlh said, once you've grouped on `prtnum`, you create groups of trucks and item types, instead of groups of trucks

Comment: Sorry, yes, removed prtnum from the group by. The count item used is irrelevant as it just counts the number of rows, it could be any field. Also you do not need an aggregate function in the select, the HAVING clause will only return rows where there is only one initial rows so no aggregation is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a group for each truck, and then per truck, demand that they carry only one type of item.  Group-wide conditions are set with the `having` clause.  Here's an example:

```
select  truck.truck_id
,       truck.driver_name
,       truck.current_location
,       sum(item.quantity) as sum_quantity
from    truck
join    box
on      box.truck_id = truck.truck_id
join    item
on      item.box_id = box.box_id
where   truck.ship_adr = '55 Alaska Rd.'
group by
        truck.truck_id
,       truck.driver_name
,       truck.current_location
having  count(distinct item.prtnum) = 1 -- Only one item type for this truck
```

There's no need to `join` the `shipment` table.  You can use the `ship_adr` from the `truck` table to filter on address.

I've added the `sum` of all quantities per truck to show how you can display group-wide statistics in addition to filtering on them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [analytic functions](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php):

```
with truck_info as (select truck.truck_id,
                           truck.driver_name,
                           truck.current_location,
                           item.prtnum,
                           item.quantity,
                           count(item.prtnum) over (partition by truck.truck_id, truck.driver_name, truck.current_location) cnt
                      from truck,
                           box,
                           item,
                           shipment
                     where item.box_id = box.box_id 
                       and box.truck_id = truck.truck_id
                       and truck.ship_adr = shipment.ship_adr 
                       and shipment.ship_adr = '55 Alaska Rd.')
select truck_id,
       driver_name,
       current_location,
       prtnum,
       quantity
from   truck_info
where  cnt = 1;
```

N.B. untested

If you've never come across analytic functions before, they're well worth learning about!